# transparent UDP and TCP Reverse Proxy for Debian

Tags: networking, debian, reverse-proxy

I have 2 Servers,

```
Frontend: Debian 7 1GB RAM (VPS)
Backend:  Windows 2012 R2 16GB RAM (Root)
```

I have now ddos protection for my FRONTEND but not for my BACKEND.
thats why i am using always an RP(Reverse Proxy) to tunnle my webservices with Pound like:

```
(Client)<--Unfiltered TRAFFIC-->[FRONTEND]<--Filtered TRAFFIC-->[BACKEND]
```

Now i dont want to redirect or use dns to solve that. 
i want to let the traffic through the FRONTEND and the same back.

there are 2 Problems to do that:

1.iptables seems sweet and good but my vps provider doesnt support that.

2.i need an transparent option where i can use the RP as Transparent proxy to forward the client ip to the backend.. (with pound i just changed in apache a rule)

so basicly i need an program For my FRONTEND that creates an bridge UDP and TCP to the BACKEND with the feature to use the Client ip.
(Problem 2 is optional but not so important...)

silent://Pound is also an load balancer but i use only the feature to bind my ssl.pem file and use different directorys for every domain etc.

Comment: This really doesn't make a lot of sense. If you want the frontend server to act as a simple conduit, why don't you directly DDOS-protect your backend server and get rid of that frontend server?

Comment: beacuse i dont want to redirect the whole traffic